# Spring Bootstrapping with Google Application Engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, web.xml

I'm currently initializing a web application without any web.xml. I'm bootstrapping a Spring `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` as follows:

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ThymeleafConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override 
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {new EmailVerificationFilter()};
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to "port" this application into a Google App Engine. But GAE requires web.xml. Is there any way I could create a web.xml and have it point to this initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work on Google Appengine. `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` requires *Servlet 3.0* environment, but Appengine supports only version *2.5*.

So, you have to use `web.xml` configuration for servlets and filters. But you can register `Configuration` classes from there too. By passing them into `DispatcherServlet` like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>SpringRootConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

PS there're also issue about support of Servlet 3.0 - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091